# What is the expected area of triangle between three points P and southwest corner(-1,-1) and south east corner (+1,-1)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

There is a square. It's corners are (-1,1), (1,1), (-1,-1) and (+1,-1). P should be chosen on this square –.P is a random point. What is the expected area of triangle between three points P and southwest corner(-1,-1) and south east corner (+1,-1) ?

Comment: Are there any limitations on the location of $P$?

Comment: There is a square. It's corners are (-1,1), (1,1), (-1,-1) and (+1,-1). P should be chosen on this square

Comment: When you say "on the square", does that include the boundary and the interior, or just the boundary?

Comment: It is an unit square. so P should be chosen on that square boundary

Comment: So $P$ is on one of the four edges and every position is equiprobable. Is it correct?

Comment: Hint: the triangle has area zero with probability $\frac14$.